Simple docker multicontainer gives error on landing page
I am trying to create a simple Spring Boot application with a PostgreSQL database using gradle and Docker. I thought I had implemented it correctly, but when I go to localhost:8080/ I get an error I am not sure why.
My application looks like this
package dat250.group22.FeedApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class FeedAppApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello Docker World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FeedAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}

I though that if I ran docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml up and went to http://localhost:8080/ I would get a string that read "Hello Docker World!", but instead I get this error:

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
this as a fallback. Mon Oct 21 21:36:47 UTC 2024 There was an
unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

And I am having difficulties debugging the console log which reads

...
feedapp_container   | 2024-10-21T21:36:47.793Z DEBUG 1 ---
[FeedApp] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver :
Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
feedapp_container   | 2024-10-21T21:36:47.821Z DEBUG 1 --- [FeedApp]
[nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting
from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404

Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:21-oracle
COPY FeedApp/build/libs/*.jar feedapp.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "feedapp.jar"]

docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres_db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    volumes:
      - C:/data/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
  backend:
    build: .
    container_name: feedapp_container
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      db-url: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres_db
      db-username: postgres
      db-password: postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always

build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
}

group = "dat250.group22"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation(platform("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-platform:6.6.0.Final"))
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.4")
    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

application.properties:
spring.application.name=FeedApp

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

# Show SQL queries and related logs
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.description.sql=trace
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug

# Server port configuration
server.port=8080

# Postgres configuration
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= ${db-url:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_db}
spring.datasource.username=${db-username:postgres}
spring.datasource.password=${db-password:postgres}

# Hibernate will create and update schema in the postgreSQL database
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

I checked the IP by running docker inspect postgres_container and using the IP address directly instead of localhost. But after I generated the docker-compose.yaml the field for the ip was an empty string, so I tried to use localhost but that did not work either.
Both the Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yaml are in the root directory. I've looked over this so many times, I've gotten stuck on what to do. What am I doing wrong here?
